# UnicodeDecodeError Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python

[image: выдает ошибку]

не понимаю, что не так вроде все верно(часть кода для бота
)
код

```
with open('dialogues.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

dialogues = []

for dialogue in data.split('\n\n'):

    replicas = []
    for replica in dialogue.split('\n')[:2]:
        replica = replica[2:].lower()
        replicas.append(replica)

    if len(replicas) == 2 and  5 < len(replicas[0]) < 25 and 5 < len(replicas[1]) < 25:
        dialogues.append(replicas)

GENERATIVE_DIALOGUES = dialogues[:50000]
```

Comment: Прикрепите код текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: with open('dialogues.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

dialogues = []

for dialogue in data.split('\n\n'):

    replicas = []
    for replica in dialogue.split('\n')[:2]:
        replica = replica[2:].lower()
        replicas.append(replica)

    if len(replicas) == 2 and  5 < len(replicas[0]) < 25 and 5 < len(replicas[1]) < 25:
        dialogues.append(replicas)

GENERATIVE_DIALOGUES = dialogues[:50000]